# как обратиться в style.css к определенному элементу?

Tags: css

есть код

```
<ul class="odin">
 <li class="dva"></li>
 <li class="dva"></li>
 <li class="dva"></li>
 <li class="dva"></li>
 <li class="dva"></li>
 <li class="dva"></li>
 <li class="dva"></li>
 <li class="dva"></li>
 <li class="dva"> //нам надо к этому элементу именно li
  <div class="nam"></div>
 </li>
</ul>
```

его менять нельзя, мне надо обратиться к последнему li элементу

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте псевдоклассы. Если нужен первый или последний дочерние элементы, то для этого есть :first-child и :last-child. Если какой-то определённый, то пишите :nth-child(n), где n - номер дочернего элемента.

```css
.odin .dva:first-child {
  color: blue;
}
.odin .dva:last-child {
  color: red;
}
.odin .dva:nth-child(5) {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul class="odin">
 <li class="dva"></li>
 <li class="dva"></li>
 <li class="dva"></li>
 <li class="dva"></li>
 <li class="dva"></li>
 <li class="dva"></li>
 <li class="dva"></li>
 <li class="dva"></li>
 <li class="dva">
  <div class="nam"></div>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: отлично) работает, но а если на другой именно конкретный элемент?)

Comment: @VladApalkov, я дополнил ответ

Comment: отлично) всем спасибо)

Answer (score -2):

Как вариант, можно задать элементу два класса class="dva ggg" и обратиться .ggg